# rating with if else in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook

I want to accomplish if else statement on this

```
if ( $rating_count >= 0 ) : ?>
    <?php echo wc_get_rating_html($average, $rating_count); ?>
    <?php if ( comments_open() ): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink() ?>#reviews" class="woocommerce-review-link" rel="nofollow">(<?php printf( _n( '%s',$review_count,'woocommerce' ), '<span class="count">' . esc_html( $review_count ) . '</span>' ); ?>)Reviews</a>
    <?php endif ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

i.e to show counts of review or echo a string 
please help.

Answer (score 0):

Refer [ElseIf/Else If.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php)

```
 if ( $rating_count >= 0 ) : ?>
    <?php echo wc_get_rating_html($average, $rating_count); ?>
<?php elseif ( comments_open() ): ?>    
    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink() ?>#reviews" class="woocommerce-review-link" rel="nofollow">(<?php printf( _n( '%s',$review_count,'woocommerce' ), '<span class="count">' . esc_html( $review_count ) . '</span>' ); ?>)Reviews</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```